# Inserting a vector into a vector of vectors

Tags: c++, vector

I am making a kind of insertion sort program that uses a vector of vectors. I want to know how I could insert a vector into a vector of vectors.

```
// constructing vector of vectors
vector< vector< int > > v_of_v;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    vector<int> row(2, i*100);
    v_of_v.push_back(row);
}

vector<int> tmp(2, 1);

// predetermined index
index = 2;

v_of_v.insert(index, tmp); // doesnt work
```

The examples I had seen just iterated through tmp and inserted each element of the vector which isn't what I was looking for. I want to be able to insert the vector itself, much like push_back can.

Comment: [`insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) takes an *iterator* as first argument, not an index. You (probably?) want to write `v_of_v.insert(v_of_v.begin() + index, tmp);`

Comment: note that inserting elements in the middle of a vector is inefficient. As it requires all following elements to shift (copy many elements). For this task using std::list is much more efficient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
v_of_v.insert(v_of_v.begin() + index, tmp);
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. I must have thought an index could be used instead of an iterator.